# C++ library for making GUIs

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I am looking for a simple C++ library for making GUIs. I tried wxWidgets and GTK, but I think both are complex.

I want your opinion on what to use. Should I learn wxWidgets or you know a better one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try Nokia's [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products). It's free, awesome **and** cross platform.

If you only need to support Windows, then you can check [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e(VS.80).aspx) or even better IMHO [Windows Forms](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/1378751/Building-a-NET-Windows-Forms-App-in-Visual-C-NET.htm) (with Managed C++).

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I think QT is nice, but you aren't claiming that QT isn't complex, are you?

Comment: The Qt library itself is complex, but doing common tasks in it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products), it's the best library out there. Even works cross platform.

You used to have to pay for a licence but they recently changed their licence to the LGPL.

Comment: The "commercial-only" release was unique to Qt for Windows. Qt for Linux has had a GPL version for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 2):

Any GUI toolkit is going to be complex -- GUIs are hard. I've heard good things about QT; I'd suggest GTK (not as complex as it looks) but it's a pain to install on Windows. I've done some work with wxPython, but I wouldn't know about Wx for C++.

Comment: That's right GTK it's a pain, I tried to make it work but in vain.

Comment: It's not so much a pain to use as a pain to install; it's my toolkit of choice if I'm not planning to be cross-platform (Linux native speaking).

Comment: "I wouldn't know about Wx for C++." - wxwidgets (http://www.wxwidgets.org/). from their site: "Welcome to the home of wxPython, a blending of the wxWidgets C++ class library with the Python programming language."

Comment: @Oren S: Right. But I've never used the C++ bindings.

Answer (score 1):

you can check [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt927w0h(VS.80).aspx) and [QT](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/index.html)

Comment: I'd say it's +1 for Qt and -1 for MFC, ... so I'm kinda confused now. :D

Comment: @AlexB +2 for Qt and -1 for MFC ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try out :)

[FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) The Fast Light Toolkit is a cross-platform Graphical User Interface (GUI) written in C++ library and can be use on UNIX/Linux, Microsoft Windows

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you may try [WTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library) instead of MFC. It is more lightweight, works slighly faster then MFC and it is open source (it is used, e.g. in Google Chrome for Windows). As a bad side, it has little documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual C++ Express edition with MFC and the new library (from BCGSoft) to create office like GUI. It's powerful and there is a lot of documentation and support on community sites:

- http://www.codeproject.com
- http://www.codeguru.com.

If you are new in programming, I think you start directly with C# and .net, WinForms offer more tools and its simple to start. and with the mono you can deploy on other platforms as mac OS or LINUX.

To start download the Visual C# Express Edition, it's free.