# Making GUIs in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ library for making GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620854/c-library-for-making-guis)

I'm sort of new to C++, and I have made a couple simple programs, but the only way to run them is in the XCode compiler. I am wondering if there are any APIs or programs that can help me make a GUI for a C++ program and include any info if possible about that library. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general choosing a GUI library depends on:

- The environment you are working on.
- Whether you want your app to have a native look or not.
- The IDE you are using.
- Your expectations in terms of portability.
- Which license you are ready to distribute your app into (GPL? LGPL? etc.).

So it's really hard to tell without knowing all these parameters.

Anyway, to name a few:

- [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) / [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/)
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/)
- [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
- [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)
- [Fox toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/)
- [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (if you are using Visual Studio and want your app to run on Windows only).

I have used *Qt* in the past and it does the job pretty well and it's very well documented.

Also, from what I remember *wxWidgets* allows you to build GUIs that will have a native look on each platform.

**[Edit]**

My assumption about *wxWidgets* is confirmed by the following statement on their website:

> Unlike other cross-platform toolkits, wxWidgets gives its applications
>   a truly native look and feel because it uses the platform's native API
>   rather than emulating the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but perhaps one of the most popular choices among many is [Qt.](http://qt.nokia.com/) It is powerful and importantly, *cross platform*.

Keep in mind it is a different ballgame if you mean GUI in terms of, say, a game interface - in this case you might need to look for something more specific, or even program your own - it's hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it so hard to ask [uncle google and aunt wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_C_or_C.2B.2B_.28including_bindings_to_other_languages.29)?

BTW take a look at [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/downloads.php). It's not as popular as metioned by others but it certainly deserves attention.

Comment: I tried, but all that came up were forum sites that were inferior to SO and din't give me good answers

Comment: @Billjk I know this is old, but I gave direct link to great comparison, so downvote and your comment pisses me off.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Xcode, you have AppKit, the Mac OS X GUI library, available.

It will require using Objective-C or Objective-C++ but is very well integrated into that environment.

Comment: I love people who downvote without explanation.